# FTP over TLS, with multiple sites hosted on the same server

Tags: ssl, certificate, ftp

Is it possible to have FTP over TLS on a server that hosts multiple websites (domains) ?

I can get certificates for any of the domains, but the problem is that I have no way of knowing to which domain does a user connect to from his client. Therefor I don't know which certificate to send to the FTP client. I know that after he sends the user and password, but not before, so I can't set up the secure connection during the FTP server start phase.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you get a SAN (aka multidomain or UCC) certificate covering all the domains (including if you use LetsEncrypt for the websites, which strongly encourages SAN) then you don't need to choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of a hostname in FTP itself. In theory a client might send the expected hostname inside the TLS handshake as server_name extension (SNI) in the ClientHello. This way the server might decide which certificate to send. But while this is common for HTTP I doubt that all FTP server and clients support it. A cursory search reveals that recent versions of ProFTPd server and FileZilla client should support it though.

Of course you could also provide a FTP server on a fixed hostname and then have domain specific home directories and credentials. This way it would work with any server or client and even without TLS (not recommended).